# Thread 'main' panicked at 'Validator in session 1 missing keys!'

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain, rococo

Now I am acquiring testnet slots in rococo, In [modify-the-chain-specification-file](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/acquire-a-testnet-slot/#modify-the-chain-specification-file) steps 5, it says `Add the public key for your account to the session keys section`. I added like this,

[image]

but while converting into raw file I got this error,

`Thread 'main' panicked at 'Validator in session 1 missing keys!',`

I didn't find much information, can you please help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should add them in [`node/src/chainspec.rs`](https://github.com/paritytech/extended-parachain-template/blob/4fe21a5a1c7dd915bb17b0a607ca4f9f60a27af4/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L426-L437) so that they are included in genesis state [for pallet-session](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2e7932fac159aa8855feeed7578319ae0e6d8296/frame/session/src/lib.rs#L420).

Comment: I don't understand, you mean adding my account `public key` instead of `Alice` [here](https://github.com/paritytech/extended-parachain-template/blob/4fe21a5a1c7dd915bb17b0a607ca4f9f60a27af4/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L282)

Comment: Correct, that is how you do it

Comment: hi @DaanvanderPlas what if we need to add pallet-session in running solo chain ?

Comment: Please make separate question